# Deploying a netcoreapp1.1 to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, f#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have netcoreapp1.1 that I am trying to publish to Azure with WebDeploy. I am able to do `dotnet publish` and deploy the contents to Azure, but the site just says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.", which suggests the app is not running.

My previous apps have used net461 as target framework and I have noticed that publishing these (with `dotnet publish`) have caused a web.config file to be created, which explains how IIS is able to run it, but this does not happen when the target framework is netcoreapp1.1.

The command I have been using to publish is this:
`dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win7-x64 --output .deploy`

Here is my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
     </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Controllers/*.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />

    <None Remove="**/*.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How am I meant to run a netcoreapp1.1 on Azure? Does it have to be self contained or is it possible to have the Azure App Service run it from dlls?

**Edit:**

Manually copying a web.config into my publish directory I am able to get the app to run. How can I make `dotnet publish` create it automatically?
Also, I am still curious about my previous questions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant for you, but here what we have come across. The way how classical ASP.NET and Core run are different. With ASP.NET Core azure runs an executable containing Kestrel Http server. It means that you can't replace existing executable while it's running. We have to stop the service copy files and run it again. However we use Octupus for deploy.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is true, but my WebDeploy configuration already handles this :) The deploy is successful, but the App doesn't start unless I manually copy a correct web.config into the publish directory.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same structure of .proj file as you do. When I run msbuild /t:restore; msbuild /t: build; msbuild /t:publish on my PC I get everything what I need in my publish folder. Do you have web.config in your project root? PS, I use VS 2017. I may share a screenshot of our project structure if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add info into you `csproj` file that you need to copy `web.config`, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="web.config">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```